# Servo starts rotating whenever it is plugged

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, servo, rtc

I am making a fish feeder using an Arduino Mega 2560, a servo motor SG90 and an RTC DS3231. I want to make it rotate twice a day, i.e. morning and 9 o'clock evening.

Whenever I plug my Arduino board to my laptop for the first time it rotates correctly during specified time 9 o'clock and I change the time to 9 o'clock 10 mins to check again and it rotates after I plug it to my laptop for 180 degrees and then rotates during the specified time.

What should I do to avoid that initial rotation?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include<Wire.h>
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <Servo.h>
     
Servo myservo;
     
int pos = 0;
RTC_DS3231 rtc;
DateTime now;
const int OnHour = 9;
const int OnMin = 15;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin();
  myservo.attach(9);
  rtc.adjust(__DATE__,__TIME__));
}
     
void loop() {
  now = rtc.now();
  Serial.print(now.hour);
  Serial.print(" hour(s), ");
  Serial.print(now.min);
  Serial.print(" minute(s)");
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay(1000);
  if (now.hour == OnHour && now.min == OnMin) {
    Serial.println("feeder ON");
    myservo.write(90); 
    delay(1000);
    myservo.write(180); 
  } else {
    Serial.println("feeder OFF");
    delay(10); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is the initial setting of the Servo?

Comment: @user52610 ... did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding the problem, but I assume you want it on for 9:00 / 9AM and 21:00 / 9 PM on for 15 minutes.

```
const int onTime1 =  9 * 60 +  0; // 9:00 AM
const int onTime2 = 21 * 60 + 30; // 9:30 PM
const int onMinutes   = 15; // Minutes

void loop()
{
  now = rtc.now();
  int nowTime = now.hour * 60 + now.min; // Minutes from current day

  if (((onTime1 <= nowTime) && (nowTime < onTime1 + onMinutes)) ||
      ((onTime2 <= nowTime) && (nowTime < onTime2 + onMinutes)))
  {
     myservo.write(90); // On
  }
  else
  {
     myservo.write(180); // Off
  }
  delay(1000); // 1 s delay
}
```

You can make the above if statement easier by:

```
  mysesrvo.write(180 - 90 * (int) (
   ((onTime1 <= nowTime) && (nowTime < onTime1 + onMinutes)) ||
   ((onTime2 <= nowTime) && (nowTime < onTime2 + onMinutes))));
```